# Is "diplomations" a coined word possibly used in journalism or in politics?

Tags: word-choice

Regarding Sony’s decision to pull “The Interview” from theaters before it’s Christmas Day release date--which decision was then reversed by Sony at the last minute--**Fox News host Megyn Kelly** said on **Jimmy Kimmel Live!** (an American talk show) the following:

> “I think it is deeply troubling. But the more I think about it the only message back has to be from the American consumer,” Kelly said. “Because what are we going to do, cut off **diplomations** with North Korea? Oh wait. Are we going to send some sort of stern message to Kim Jong-un that he is going to understand? Probably not.”

Is "diplomations" a coined word possibly used in journalism or in politics?
Or did she misspeak the wrong word inadvertently (possibly for "diplomatic relations")?

And here's [the link to a news article (including the video)](http://www.thewrap.com/fox-news-megyn-kelly-talks-the-interview-doesnt-know-if-she-did-the-right-...%20/) : (The relevant portion starts at about 26 seconds into the video in case you want to watch it.)

**EDIT**

The question is not whether "theoretically" the word could be considered to be made up of two existing words "diplomatic" + "relations". In context, you can easily figure out what she meant by that word if you watch her interview.

Before posting the question, I've checked all the dictionaries, slang dictionaries, news articles, Google and whatnot. I could not find a single instance of the word "diplomation(s)" being used. At least not in English.

So the question is really about whether the word is actually in use if only in journalism and/or politics, unbeknownst to all the search that I've done that proved nothing to that effect.

Comment: *diplomations:* ? Portmanteau,  *diplomatic* + *relations*

Comment: See also, *diplomation* in esperanto here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diplomation

Comment: You need to be careful when analyzing extemporaneous discussions. People often make slips of the tongue like this.

Comment: It's a coined word like ginormous.

Comment: FWIW, to me on the tape it just sounds like she misspoke, simply meaning "diplomatic relations". It doesn't sound like she was trying to coin a new word at all.

Comment: Even if she misspoke, this word is useful and everybody understands what it means, so why not use it?

Comment: @jocap, Unfortunately, being useful and understandable won't necessarily make the word or any word for that matter enter the legitimate English vocabulary. Your suggestion that it be used only suggests that it is not currently being used.

Comment: @JK2: You're right, but I just like the word and I'd see how I might use it sometime.

Answer (score 4):

It's a shortened version of 'Diplomatic Relations', a word that she probably coined on the fly.

Similar to Confuzzled (confused+puzzled) or Segfault (segmentation+fault)

Comment: I'd go with @DaemonOfTheWest since they're the first one to post an actual answer. Direct quotes during live/unscripted shows can't be relied upon for 100% accuracy. Even edited printed media has to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: You say "coined on the fly" and I read "misspoke" unless of course you provide some credible source.

Comment: coined on the fly, not misspoke. Basically, you intentionally combine two words because you think the audience will know what you mean. It's similar to slang.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portmanteaus They don't create themselves.

Comment: If you're the only one who is using the "slang", it's not even that. We don't know for sure whether she intended to use that word or she didn't but misspoke. And it actually doesn't matter whether it's intentional or inadvertent error on her part, is it? All that matters is nobody here can prove that that word is in real use among native speakers of English, be it slang, jargon, or informal. If it is not in real use, it's not English. Yet.

Comment: Even your wikipedia link doesn't have that word. If anything, the link proves "diplomation" is not use.

Comment: Oh, hooray, you proved something. Want a cookie?

I meant "similar to slang", if you even read my post. Slang is created when a way of unconventionally expressing something becomes popular. This is similar, but is more of a portmanteau.

Comment: If it has to be a portmanteaus, it's a makeup portmanteaus. So it's not entered English yet. Unless you prove otherwise.

Comment: There is no real definition of 'English' - there is no official upkeeping of what is english. Words are added and removed through years. If a word is used enough and everyone speaking the language understands what it means, it's English. The English Language is just a way of communication. The definition of 'entering' english is not defined. Similarly, all portmanteaus are made up. They're all blendings of words that the community can understand, rendering them relevant.

Comment: There is no 'official categorization' of what is in the English Language and what is not. In fact, a language is just a structure - a layout of the way entities of speech are supposed to be combined. Verbs, nouns, adjectives etc. are the English Language. The words in a language come and go.

Comment: I don't need a lecture on "What is English?". All I tried to say was your answer doesn't really address the call of the question. Please go READ the title of the question. "Is “diplomations” a coined word possibly used in journalism or in politics?" If you have proof that it's actually being used in journalism/politics, then provide the proof. If you can't find it, then it's not being used.

Comment: No, it's not in journalism or politics. I never stated it was in journalism or politics. I thought "she probably coined on the fly" was clue enough that it's not commonly used in journalism or politics because it was created then and there. Happy?

Comment: Even a news anchor doesn't have the right or power to "create a word on the fly". If a non-native speaker guest had used that word in exactly the same talk show, you wouldn't have said they "created it" and justify their "mistake", would you have? You probably would have called it "broken English". The identity of the speaker doesn't make the wrong word a legit one.

Comment: It doesn't. But what she said was still english. He created a  portmanteau on the fly, and because people can easily understand what she means it can be considered english. Hence my lecture earlier. Moving this convo to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20021/discussion-between-daemonofthewest-and-jk2).

Answer (score 2):

I think, even if it was a technical word–only used in small circles e.g. in journalism or in politics–you would still expect it to show up in Google Ngram Viewer, which scans publications.
It does not show up, and therefore it is not, and never has been, a 'living' word.

Comment: There are numerous "modern" expressions spoken by native speakers that Ngram fails to pick up on. The fact that diplomations is not recorded proves only that editors, journalists etc. have not used this term in the *past*. Who knows if is journalese jargon used in newsrooms etc. However, it seems "unlikely" at best.

Answer (score 2):

The word **diplomations** does not currently exist in the English language. So it leaves the possibility Kelly misspeaking and intending to use another word, intentionally creating a new term or inadvertently creating a term.

One of the most famous examples from the past few years is Sarah Palin's use of the word **refudiate**. There's a difference in a speaker explicitly stating, "I think there's a new term for this and I'm going to call it **x**." Someone might disagree with the term and it may not catch on, but the intent in creating new terminology is explicit.

When it comes to political neologisms, if one uses existing words, the intent is sometimes assumed such as in the case of terms like "Failed State" or "Pro-choice." These are existing words that are combined in their normal meanings to portray a certain political situation or ideology.

For lexicographers creating modern dictionaries, there is always the entire debate of prescriptive vs descriptive. Often English dictionaries are updated with words that have become popular or common. They're less about dictating what correct usage should be.

In the case of Palin, the perception of her intelligence by the English speaking population quite likely influenced the fact that "refudiate" didn't enter the common vernacular. Other presidents have introduced entirely new terms, often inadvertently. An example is the term "belittle" which was coined by Thomas Jefferson.

Answer (score 1):

Diplomatic Relations is a single concept represented by multiple words. I have a feeling the newscaster smushed them together because it was just faster and she deals with it quite often. Kind of like an abbreviation.

Comment: I guess you wanted this undeleted. If not, just delete it again. You could simply have provided a new answer since the edit was so radical.

Comment: I kind of rethought my answer on the subway :) I was actually going to put in a new answer but the website prompted me to edit the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no word as Diplomation.. there is diploma, diplomatic, diplomacy etc. Kelly is just trying to be inventive. I even got red underline for word Diplomation (meaning error) while typing out this answer to you.